# Overlapping of textbox cause dropdown functionality error

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, dropdown

[image: Problem of the dropdown]

I created a dropdown, but the textbox is overlapping it. I wanted to create it like a normal dropdown. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
    <title>The Sun – Telling It As It As</title>
    
    <!---CSS link--->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">
    
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css">

\</head\>
\<body\>

    <!---HEADER--->
    <header>
        <a href ="#home" class="logo"><img src="img/Logo/logo.png"></a>
    
        <div class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></div>
    
        <div>
            <ul class="navbar">
                
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#listings">Listings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
                    <a href="#login">Login</a>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
        </div>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

\</body\>
\</html\>
```

CSS

```
#menu-icon
    {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    .navbar
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: -600px;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: white;
        text-align: left;
        transition: all .40s ease; 
    }

    .navbar .active
    {
        top: 60px;
    }

    .navbar a 
    {
        display: block;
        padding: 1rem;
        margin: 1rem;
    }
```

I wanted to create a normal, error-free dropdown list. Such as in amazon, ebay, propertyguru and many more related to classified website.

Comment: add css `z-index: 9999` to your navbar class

Comment: You can resolve this by adding `z-index: 9999` to your dropdown or navbar, and please put a functional snippet.

Comment: can you share the full code to make changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing higher z-index value to navbar class can resolve this bug

update your navbar class in css as shown below

```
   .navbar {
        position: absolute;
        z-index : 999;
        top: -600px;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: white;
        text-align: left;
        transition: all .40s ease;   }
```

Comment: It resolved, thank you for making my day special bro